# same issue three separate laptops

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, wireless, networking, dell

I have three different laptops that have developed the same issue at about the same time.  It is the missing firmware for wifi has like disappeared and no matter what I do to fix the problem it all fails. 
Laptop 1.) Dell Inspiron 1525 running Ubuntu 14.04
Laptop 2.) Dell Latitude 610 Dual boot Vector Linux (Slackware) and Lubuntu/gnome 13.10
Laptop 3.) HP Pavilion 1000. Ubuntu 12 something cannot be upgraded due to graphics card that is old.

Laptop 2.)  Connects to the wifi on the Vector Linux side only.

My wifi is seen and is used by 2 Kindles and 1 Chromebook.

The three laptops running the Ubuntu all started to not connect to the wifi at nearly the same time.  Laptop 1.)  just out of the clear blue stopped.  Followed by Laptop 2 and 3,  with the exception of the Vector Linux on Laptop 2.

I have been to the forums and tried to use the instructions to install the firmware and after probing on all 3 machines nothing shows.

I just spent nearly 40 hours trying to solve this myself and am at a loss.

I thought there might be a problem with the router,  because to save electricity at night we shut off everything all power.   However when we turn back on the next day the Kindles and the Chromebook and Vector Linux all connect. 
So now we moved the cable modem and the router to another plug in and leave them on and I have tried to re-install the firmware,  just trying any ole' idea that come into my head.  Needless to say unless tethered to the ether net cable anything Ubuntu cannot get online.

Prior to this all three were running on the wifi without a hiccup,  for years.

So I don't know what is going on any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Please tell us what firmware seems to be missing and the details about one of the laptops: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but judging from the fact that three laptops stopped working at the same time I'm guessing that something changed in the configuration of your wifi network, which causes your Ubuntu laptops to not play along.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it seems there was a config change with the router. might be an ip block due to the fact you can get on with the one version of linux on the dual boot it's not a mac block. you could try checking the network config and see if it's static or dynamic (dynamic is usually what you want set up) unless you have set it to be static.